# How to get descendants with a specific tag name and text in protractor?

Tags: xpath, protractor

I have the following structure (it's just for sample). In protractor, I am getting the top element by id. However, the other elements do not have id's. I need to get the "label" element that contains the text '20'. Is there an easy way in protractor to select the element with a specific tag that contains a specific text from all the descendants of a parent element?

```
  <pc-selector _... id="Number1">
    <div ...></div>
    <div ...>
          <div ...>
                <check-box _...>
                   <div _ngcontent-c25="" ...>
                       <label _ngcontent-c25="">
                          <input _ngcontent-c25="" type="checkbox">
                          <span _ngcontent-c25="" class="m-checkbox__marker"></span>
                       20 More text to follow</label>
                    </div>
                 </check-box>
         </div>
    </div>
  </pc-selector>
```

I could't find anythitng, so I have tried with xpath, but protractor complains that my xpath is invalid:

```
parentElement = element(by.id('Number1'));
return parentElement.element(by.xpath(".//label[contains(text(),'20'))]"));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an additional bracket in your [contains(text(),'20')**)**] which is likely causing you issue but there are multiple other ways this can be achieved using a single XPath or chaining other locators.

The process is that you must find the div with the correct id first and then locate the label that is a child of it.

```
//Xpath
element(by.xpath("//pc-selector[@id='Number1']//label[contains(text(),'20')]"));

//Chained CSS
element(by.id('Number1')).element(by.cssContainingText('label','20'));
```

You also may be interested to learn about [xpath axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes) which can allow us to do very dynamic selection.

Comment: It works when I run this xpath: "//*[@id=Number1']//label" and I get all the label elements. However, once I try to filter them by text "//*[@id='Number1']//label[contains(text(),'20')]", it cannot find any element. However, the chained css worked, thanks!

Comment: Yeah as you mentioned `//*[@id=Number1']//label` will return all label elements so I didn't feel that satisfied your question. I think I should have used a dot in place of the text() (`//pc-selector[@id='Number1']//label[contains(.,'20')`) but not 100% certain. Did you retry your original attempt with the unnecessary bracket removed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the direct xpath to access the label.

```
element(by.xpath("//*[@id='Number1']//label"));
```